# "Connection reset" exception with Apache HttpClient 4.5 on Mac

Tags: java, macos, apache, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to get up to **1000** threads to send HTTP request simultaneously. Yet it seems on Mac I am hitting some limit, which causes Apache HTTPClient to return exception:

```
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://my.url:80: Connection reset
```

The limit appears to be somewhere between 200 and 300 concurrent connections.

I created a simple app and able to reproduce the issue even with that app:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

public class App implements Runnable
{
    private static final int NUMBER_THREADS = 1000;

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[NUMBER_THREADS];
        for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_THREADS; i++)
        {
            threads[i] = new Thread(new App()); 
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_THREADS; i++)
        {
            threads[i].start(); 
        }
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://my.url/test.html");
        CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
        try 
        {
            System.out.println( System.nanoTime() + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " started" );
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            System.out.println( System.nanoTime() + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " finished" );
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally 
        {
            try 
            {
                if(response != null)
                {
                    response.close();
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I updated some Mac settings, but that didn't help anything:

```
> sysctl -a | grep files
kern.maxfiles = 12288
kern.maxfilesperproc = 10240
kern.maxfiles: 12288
kern.maxfilesperproc: 10240
kern.num_files: 3202
> ulimit -n 10240
> ulimit -n
10240
> sysctl -a | grep somax
kern.ipc.somaxconn: 128
> sudo sysctl -w kern.ipc.somaxconn=2048
Password:
kern.ipc.somaxconn: 128 -> 2048
> sysctl -a | grep somax
kern.ipc.somaxconn: 2048
```

So I want to understand where this limit is coming from? OsX / Apache HttpClient itself? And is it possible to control it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Upgrade to latest MacOS 10.11/El Capitan did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was indeed with maxfiles, but I was not changing them right. [This](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/tuning/open-files-limit/) article helped me to solve it by showing the correct procedure for updating file limits on Mac OS X Yosemite / El Capitan.

1. Create and update /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist file:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
     <plist version="1.0">
       <dict>
         <key>Label</key>
           <string>limit.maxfiles</string>
         <key>ProgramArguments</key>
           <array>
             <string>launchctl</string>
             <string>limit</string>
             <string>maxfiles</string>
             <string>65536</string>
             <string>65536</string>
           </array>
         <key>RunAtLoad</key>
           <true/>
         <key>ServiceIPC</key>
           <false/>
       </dict>
     </plist>
   ```
2. Create /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxproc.plist file:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple/DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
     <plist version="1.0">
       <dict>
         <key>Label</key>
           <string>limit.maxproc</string>
         <key>ProgramArguments</key>
           <array>
             <string>launchctl</string>
             <string>limit</string>
             <string>maxproc</string>
             <string>2048</string>
             <string>2048</string>
           </array>
         <key>RunAtLoad</key>
           <true />
         <key>ServiceIPC</key>
           <false />
       </dict>
   ```
3. Add .bashprofile with the following lines:

   ```
   ulimit -n 65536
   ulimit -u 2048
   ```
4. Restart your system